# Can I ask questions about how to structure a project

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I have a project which needs to be 'split' into two (for 2 different types of end user (a seeder and consumer)). I won't go into details, but, would this type of question (knowing what options are available in this situation) be on topic here?

Answer (score 1):

As stated this could degenerate into a non constructive list of people's favourite structure.

However, if you are clear and specific over the details of the problem you need to solve then it should be OK - as it's a design question.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I will post then and see what those who judge will determine! Thank you